# How to execute a method for a specific list element in C#?

Tags: c#, list

My Code looks like that:

```
public class Artikel : List<Datenschicht.tb_Artikel>
{
     ....
     public void DoSomething()
     {
     ..
     }
}
```

Now i want to do sth like that:

```
Artikel[0].DoSomething();
```

How can i get this number (0) in the method "DoSomething"?

Thank you for your Help!

Comment: It is flawed, or you made an illposed problem

Comment: Did you mean to write `DoSomething(Artikel[0]);` ?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough for anyone to give you an answer. You need to state what your intention is more clearly. Specifically what you are trying to do with Artikel[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the instance of `tb_Artikel` to know what index it occupies in the `List<>` structure.  If so this is not possible.  Objects don't have any knowledge of their containers.  Primarily because objects can be contained in multiple `List<>` at any given time.  Which number would it choose then?

One option though is to simply have the `DoSomething` take the `int` value directly.  Then let it choose the value from itself to operate on

```
void DoSomething(int index) {
  this[index].DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a basic misunderstanding of OO question. The 'Artikel' type declares 'DoSomething'. 'Datenschicht.tb_Artikel' does not. Artikel[0] returns the first object inside the 'Artikel' instance. Items are declared to be of type 'Datenschicht.tb_Artikel', and thus do not have a DoSomething method. Unless you put one there.

If the intention is to have a method that does something to a specified item, you could write a DoSomething(int i) method, which accepts the index, retrieves it, and then does the something with it.

Answer (score 0):

`Artikel[0]` is of `Datenschicht.tb_Artikel` type, so I'm pretty sure there will be no access to `DoSomething` method from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't as the object has no knowledge that it is in an array.

If you need the index you can pass that in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with wasabi on this one. You could implement `void DoSomething()` as static extension method to `Datenschicht.tb_Artikel`, if that is a sensible thing to do in your program.